# What dependencies need to be installed to make dotnet build and restore works on Ubuntu 20.04 system

Tags: azure, dotnet

I am planning to create build and release pipeline using Ubuntu azure agent.

Dotnet Build and Restore commands are failing. My project is from a dotnet core 3.1 version.

Please let me know the minimum dependencies to build, restore and run my tests (using dotnet test)

Answer (score 0):

Installed the dotnet runtime 3.1 version as mentioned in
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu